# Best Data Structure in java to search all overlapt between two spatio temporal event

Tags: java, search, data-structures, overlap, date-range

I have two different event defined in two different space and time range.
They are defined in the space by KilometerInitial, KilometerFinal.
In the time by InstantDateInitial and InstantDateFinal.

I'd like to finde the most efficent solution to find all overlap between one Event vs allEvent saved in the data structure.

I am searching something like DataStructureEvents.Overlapping( Event )

I tried to use Treeset data structure , I used headset  to cut Event in spatial dimension that are started after the end of the event.
After that i scroll backwards to find another event enpoint untill I reach a theshold that I define using business rules.

But I Hope that there are more efficent way to do it!

Comment: Special tree data structures for such situations exist. I believe that [*k*-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is one. Search for more.

Answer (score 0):

There are specialized temporal data structures and databases that can do that. However, I think very few of them have free open-source implementations. The keyword to search for is *"spatio-temporal indexing"*.

As an alternative I think you can simply use any spatial index by encoding your data into two-dimensional "rectangles", the first dimension is distance, the second is time. Then you can use window queries to find any "rectangle" (=event) that overlap with your any given event.

If you are looking for spatial data structures in Java, there is for example the [Tinspin Index Library](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer). I suggest trying the R-Tree, quadtree (qtplain or qthypercube) or the PH-tree.

If you have *a lot* of data and spatial indexing is not fast enough, you may want to look into *spatial join* indexing and querying.